# VS 2017 Building executable with symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I get a `Module was built without symbols.` message when I try to run my application. How do I build my application with symbols? There's doesn't seem to be anything useful in Properties > Debug. In Build > Advanced Build Settings, Output > Debugging Information is set to full. What other options are supposed to be set?

Comment: _Which_ module was built without symbols?

Comment: @SLaks The actual executable. It says `Loaded 'C:\Users[...]exename.exe'. Module was built without symbols.`

Comment: *how* are you "...run my application"? Is this from VS or from the command line/windows explorer?

Comment: @Igor From VS. I hit the Start button on the toolbar with configuration set to Debug.

Comment: You are running the debug configuration and not the release build? (This is in Debug->Configuration Manager rather than the project settings).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I have no Debug > Configuration Manager. I am using VS 2017.